# Can we use a CLI tool in linux, if we have not installed the programming language using which that tool built?

Tags: python, command-line-tool

Suppose I want to use a CLI tool which was previously built using python, and I don't have python installed on my system. Am I still able to use that CLI tool ? (without installing python). If yes, then how it made to work ? Will it be same if tool was built using other ways instead of python ?

Comment: This question belongs on superuser. It depends on what libraries it uses, whether the tool is packaged and distributed as a self-sufficient binary or is compiled and installed locally after downloading. You might want to look into how software is packaged and distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if it is interpreted then you will need the language on the system (or like Java, which needs a runtime installed).
There are tools available to produce an executable for Python, so it doesn't need to be ran with `python main.py`, for example [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html).

If the tool/program was compiled into a binary blob, like how C/C++ compiles to a binary executable, it can be used without the libraries/language used to build it.